# NSDictionary - List all

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In a NSMutableDictionary like this:

```
[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
[NSString stringWithString:firstName], @"NAME",
[NSNumber numberWithFloat:familyName], @"SURNAME",
nil];
```

How can all of its elements be converted to the NSString? with the requirement that names and surnames are arranged in string like this: "name, surname, name, surname..."?

This gives a string with all the names but not surnames:

```
NSString * result = [[urlArray valueForKey:@"NAME"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
```

Is there a way similar to the one above to create a string with all the values of NSMutableDictionary?

Comment: I don't quite understand the [NSNumber numberWithFloat:familyName] part. I assume familyName is a string? If not, I apologize and I understand the code, but not how a familyName can be a float. <g>

Comment: omission, but well noticed... positive comment rating well deserved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", [urlArray valueForKey:@"SURNAME"], [urlArray valueForKey:@"NAME"]];
```

The `%@` represents an objective-c object for more details see the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265)

Answer (score 0):

The code to make a NSString from an NSDictionary may look like (if you're trying to print out everything in the NSDictionary)

```
NSMutableString* mutableString = [NSMutableString string];
NSDictionary* dictionary;

for(NSString* key in [dictionary allKeys]) 
{
    [mutableString appendString:[[dictionary objectForKey:key] description]];
}
```